# Chrome moving content to left when open hidden element and not returning it when closing element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alignment, scrollbar

This is my first question and I use this site a lot for answers so hoping to get more involved.

I have a strange Chrome/CSS related problem. On a site I have built there is a hidden menu which is massive when you open it.

The problem is that if you are on Chrome and there is no initial scrollbar if you open the menu and it creates the need for a scrollbar it moves all of the content left but when you close the menu and the scrollbar disappears the body content moves back but the site header stays to the left.

I have added screenshots to demo this. I cannot give access to the site pages as it has sensitive business data on it.

Initial page load:
I can only add 2 links as don't have enough points! :(
This image is the same as the Menu Closed image but all aligned.

Menu open:
[The menu here is open and has the dark background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VtQi.png)

Menu closed:
[The menu is now closed and you can see the alignment is now off. You can see the background white is shifted in the top right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI7Uh.png)

This is a basic example of the CSS:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="visible-xs col-xs-3">
                <a href="#" class="menu-option mobile menu-toggle"><i class="icon-handle"></i></a>
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <a href="/" class="topbar-logo">
                    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="visible-xs col-xs-3"></div><!--col-->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-2  no-padding-right visible-xs">
                <div class="page-title mobile">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                </div>
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-push-4 col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
                <div class="topbar-block dealership">
                    TEST
                </div><!--topbar-block-->
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-push-4 col-sm-3 visible-xs no-padding-left">
                <div class="topbar-block dealership">
                    <span class="topbar-block-smalltext">TEST</span>
                </div><!--topbar-block-->
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-pull-3 col-sm-2">
                <div class="topbar-block">
                    <span class="topbar-block-title">TEST Code</span>
                    <span class="topbar-block-bigtext">TEST</span>
                </div><!--topbar-block-->
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-3 col-sm-2">
                <div class="topbar-block">
                    <span class="topbar-block-title">Area</span>
                    <span class="topbar-block-bigtext"> 1-10 </span>

                </div><!--topbar-block-->
            </div><!--col-->

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1">
                <a href="/log-out.php" class="topbar-block">
                    <span class="topbar-block-title">Logout</span>
                    <i class="icon-padlock-closed topbar-block-icon"></i>
                </a><!--topbar-block-->
            </div><!--col-->

        </div><!--row-->

    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--topbar-->

<div class="mainmenu-spread">
    <div class="container spaced">
        <div class="row page-controls">

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="/api/auto-aimm-login.php?redirect=https://www.hyundaiaimm.co.uk/order-history/" class="menu-option" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="AIMM Marketing Fund"><i class="icon-moneybox menu-option-icon"></i> <span class="moneybox-text">= N/A</span></a>
                </div><!--col-->

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                                            <a href="/golden-ticket/" class="menu-option golden-ticket-count">
                        <i class="icon-golden-ticket menu-option-icon"></i>
                        <span>
                            <span class="text-gold">748</span> GOLDEN TICKETS <span class="hidden-991">REDEEMED</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div><!--col-->

        </div><!--row-->

        <nav class="mainmenu">
            <h2 class="mainmenu-title">Navigation</h2>

            <div class="row">

            </div><!--row-->
        </nav><!--mainmenu-->

    </div><!--container-->
</div><!-- mainmenu-spread -->
```

It is the topbar that is not moving back but there is nothing to suggest why? Is it a Chrome thing?

I googled for this problem but there were just loads of things related to Chrome scrollbar complaints and couldn't find anything on here either.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer to this.

The solution to the alignment was to add overflow:hidden; to the .topbar when the menu is closed. I'm not exactly sure why this was the fix but it worked.
We also experienced a doulbe scrollbar on pages where the content was deeper than the monitor and the menu open. To sort this we added display:none; to the main page content when the menu was opened.

Thanks if anyone looked at this and tried to think of a solution!